# Sql insert,select using CodeIgniter

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I have a problem and do not know how to solve, please help me, So I have 2 tables in my database:

```
dosar
id  name  date  fk_verificator  fk_administrator  fk_user
user
id name surname is_verificator  is_admin
```

I create and insert into my db, in fk_verificator is stored the id from user who is verificator and in fk_administrator is sored the id from user who is administratr, So my question is it's possible to create a query to get for this dosar 2 users from user table(one user who is administrator and one who is admin) or need to create an auxiliary table? thnx in advance.Please help me
So for example if I have:

```
dosar table:
id   name       fk_verif   fk_admin   fk_user
1   dosarNr.1     2          1           1

user
id     name     surname   is_verific   is_admin
 1     name1    surname1     N           Y
 2     name2    surname2     Y           N
```

Now in this select I want to get:

```
dosar1    name1   surname1   name2   surname2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your expected result set you have to join your user table twice with doser in order to get the name for admin and the person who verifies records

### Mysql Query

```
select 
d.name,
u1.name name1,
u1.surname surname1,
u1.name name2,
u1.surname surname2
from dosar d
join `user` u1 on(d.fk_admin = u1.id and u1.is_admin = 'Y')
join `user` u2 on(d.fk_verif = u2.id and u2.is_verific = 'Y')
```

### [**`FIDDLE  DEMO`**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/991cb/3)

### Active Record Query

```
$result=$this->db->select('d.name,
                   u1.name name1,
                   u1.surname surname1,
                   u1.name name2,
                   u1.surname surname2')
          ->from('dosar d')
          ->join("user u1','d.fk_admin = u1.id and u1.is_admin = 'Y'")
          ->join("user u2','d.fk_verif = u2.id and u2.is_verific = 'Y'")
          ->get()
          ->result();
```

### Running simple Query

```
$sql="select 
    d.name,
    u1.name name1,
    u1.surname surname1,
    u1.name name2,
    u1.surname surname2
    from dosar d
    join `user` u1 on(d.fk_admin = u1.id and u1.is_admin = 'Y')
    join `user` u2 on(d.fk_verif = u2.id and u2.is_verific = 'Y')";
$this->db->query($sql);
```

Answer (score 0):

This question is hard to understand, but it sounds like you need a join:

```
$this->db->join($this->_users_table . ' as u', ' u.id = dosar.admin_id');
```

Comment: well, it was a shoot in the dark. Its almost impossible to tell what you're asking here. Do you need to know how to select? <code>$this->db->select();</code>